# How do I know if I have enough features for a ML

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-selection

Is there any way I can figure out if what the data I have can provide any reasonable prediction? Say, if I have 20 features, for example, how do I check that these features are actually useful for neural network. I am not sure if correlation can provide me any help here. Is there any other way?

Thanks!

Comment: Build a neural network and evaluate whether it's good enough at solving your problem or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I don't see any other way than to just **build** a predictive model by using those 20 (or less, if they are correlated) features, and review model performance statistics -- like **AUC** -- to assess whether the available features provide a reasonable amount of predictive power or not. For instance, if the AUC value comes out to be very close to 0.50, then that would imply that the input features are insufficient to produce a strong/accurate prediction for the target feature.

**PS:** In order to achieve robust and generalizable results, you'd have to utilize cross validation.